# Does socket.io needs its counterpart on a server?

Tags: socket.io

I would like to use socket.io or engine.io on client, but does it implies having a corresponding implementation on the server ? so socket.io on Client and a Java server with socket.io for instance ? Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, a socket.io client must be talking to a socket.io server on the other end.  socket.io is its own protocol on top of webSockets so you must have a reciprocal server on the other end that speaks the same protocol.

There are implementations of socket.io server for many server-side languages, including Java, Javascript, C++, C#, etc...